# K-means in R: complete case analysis followed by nearest-neighbor assignment for partial data

Tags: clustering, missing-data, unsupervised-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I have a dataset of 3K observations with only 162 being a complete case.
I have read [here](https://www.displayr.com/5-ways-deal-missing-data-cluster-analysis/) that it is possible to run knn on the complete cases and then conduct a nearest neighbour assignment for partial data.

Maybe someone can reference or provide an example of R implementation of the nearest-neighbour assignment of partial data?

Answer (score 0):

There is no knn clustering.

You probably meant *k-means*.

Yes, you can run k-means on the complete cases only, and then assign the remaining rows to the nearest cluster center.